# Find $2100^{2105}$ (mod $13$).

Tags: discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic

Here's what I have so far:
$2100^{2105} ≡ 7^{2105} ≡ (7^5)^{421} ≡ (16807)^{421} ≡ (11)^{421} ≡ (-2)^{421}$
However, I do not know how to further simplify this. Do I need to keep going on this path or should I have simplified differently somewhere?

Comment: Do you know [Fermat's little theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat's_little_theorem)?

Comment: Do u know fermat's theorom?

Comment: I do not. Is that the only way to do this? I did a quick Google search, but I don't understand how to apply it.

Comment: Because 13 is prime, $\phi(13) = 12$ and in particular, $k^{12}\equiv 1$ (mod 13) for any $k\ne 0$ ( mod 13).  So you can take the exponent mod 12.  Using what you have so far then, you get $(-2)^{1}$ mod 13, or 11 mod 13.

Comment: FLT is worth learning.  But without it $7^2=49=-3;7^3=-21=5;7^4=35=-4;7^5=-28=-2;7^6=-14=-1$ so $7^{12}=1$ so $7^{2105}=7^{905}=7^{65}=7^{5}=-2$

Answer (score 3):

Using Fermat's Little Theorem, $2100\equiv7\pmod{13}$

$$2100^{2105}\equiv7^{2105}\pmod{13}$$

Now as $(7,13)=1$ and $2105\equiv5\pmod{12}$

$$7^{2105}\pmod{13}\equiv7^5\pmod{13}$$

Now $7^2\equiv-3\pmod{13},7^4\equiv(-3)^2\equiv9\implies7^5\equiv7\cdot9\equiv-2\equiv11$

Answer (score 0):

Since
$$(-2)^6=64\equiv-1 \mod 13$$
It follows 
\begin{align*}
(-2)^{421}&\equiv (-2)^{6\times 70+1} \mod 13\\
&\equiv(-1)^{70}(-2) \mod 13\\
&\equiv 11 \mod 13
\end{align*}